# Test Windows Store App as if I didn't purchase an IAP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, win-universal-app

I'm testing an app with an IAP. I want to test the change when purchasing the IAP, but I can't because I have already purchased it. Is there a way to "unpurchase" it? (It's a `Durable`, not `Consumable`.)

I know I can workaround such as by adding code to imitate the IAP purchase. The point is I want to *verify* it works, not just assume my workaround is correct.

Answer (score 0):

By using `CurrentAppSimulator`, you can do that by simulate the purchase status and change it as you want, and your app will behave as it's not begin simulated :)

In this article, there's a full implementation and docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to make an actual purchase to verify the process. So I need to "unpurchase" the IAP.

Comment: You can't do that! why don't you simulate it and then 'unpurchase' it by simulate it again ?

Answer (score 0):

When you test **Release** version in the emulator, and you have fresh deployed version of the app in it - you can purchase IAP this way. It will be done in the "emulator way" so no money required, it will be just like you would buy/cancel it in the real app.

It's just not as much convenient compared to *CurrentAppSimulator* because IAP state isn't preserved when you relaunch the emulator. 
*CurrentAppSimulator* is convenient way to check different combinations of purchased IAPs, but isn't required to check if IAPs are working.

Remember to have an IAP submitted in Dev Center. Otherwise it won't work. If you have it, then it will look exactly the same way as it is in released app. The image will be there with title, description and options to purchase.

Comment: Thanks. But are you referring to the phone emulator? This is not a phone app. Just a regular Windows 10 app.